# Is there a way to match this with Regex instead of a loop?

Tags: java, regex

I've got this function here, which counts curly braces outside of quotes, ignoring those within: (pass a string and a '{' or '}' depending on my use)

```java
public static int countCurlyBraces(String s, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char cr : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (cr == '"')
            if (stack.isEmpty())
                stack.push(cr);
            else
                stack.pop();

            if (stack.size() == 1 && cr == c)
                count++;
    }
    return StringUtil.countMatches(s, c) - count;
}
```

I am trying to replace this with a regex but I am having a bit of trouble, is it even possible?

```java
public static int countCurlyBraces(String s, char c) {
    Matcher a = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)[" + c + "](.*?)\"").matcher(s);
    int count = 0;

    while (a.find()) 
        count++;

    return StringUtil.countMatches(s, c) - count;
}
```

An example string I use for testing is:

> sdfg"srfg{rmjy#"rmyrmy{rymundh"ecfvr{cerv#"fes{dc"cf2234TC@$#ct234"etw243T@#$c"nhg

This should return a count of 2, ignoring the two curly braces  contained within quotes. The Regex expression sees all the curly braces as contained within quotes and outputs a 0.

the document looks like:

```
LOCALE
user="XXXXXXX" time=1561234682/* "26-Jun-2019 23:00:03" */
{
  LOCALE="XXXXXXX"
}
SITE NAME="XxxXXxxx"
 user="XXXXXX" time=1568532503/* "26-Jun-2019 23:00:03" */
{
  SYSTEM_NAME="XXX-NNNNN"
  SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER="{XXXX-XXXX-XXX_XXX-XX}"
  SYSTEM_ID=NNNNN
  SYSTEM_ZONE_NAME="XXXXXX"
  DEFAULT_COMMUNICATION_TYPE=REDUNDANT
  IP_ADDR_AUTO_GEN=T
  PP_LAD="aGx{4"
  PVQ_LIMIT=0.5
  BCK_LIMIT=0.3
  MNN_LIMIT=0.1
  COMPANY_NAME=""
  DISPLAY_VERSION_CONTROL_ENABLED=F
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this can be done, in your code you are keeping track if you have seen an odd or even number of `"` marks up till that point. As far as I know, regular expressions do not count.

Comment: Just in case: If you are trying to parse JSON then I recommend just using an existing JSON parser, such as Jackson.

Comment: The document is not a JSON and looks like what I am adding to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is a very roundabout way to achieve what you want and it is rather inefficient.

Firstly, you're iterating through the string and counting the characters *inside* the quotes, then iterating through the whole string again counting *all* the matching characters and subtracting the number of matching characters inside quotes... whyyy? Instead just count the ones outside the quotes like you want.

Secondly, by using `s.toCharArray()` you are essentially holding duplicate data and doubling the memory footprint of your string; Instead just access its data through `charAt`.

Thirdly, using a stack to keep track of if you are inside quotes is unnecessary; Instead just flip a boolean value.

Here's my notes on your method:

```
public static int countCurlyBraces(String s, char c) {
    Deque<Character> stack = ...; // I'm assuming 'stack' is some kind of Deque
    int count = 0;
    // doubling memory usage of the string by copying the chars into another array with 's.toCharArray()'
    // for each character in that string...
    for (char cr : s.toCharArray()) {
        // using a stack to keep track if you are inside quotes? just flip a boolean instead
        if (cr == '"')
            if (stack.isEmpty())
                stack.push(cr);
            else
                stack.pop();

        // if inside quotes and the character matches the target, then count it..
        // I thought you wanted to count the characters outside the quotes?
        if (stack.size() == 1 && cr == c)
            count++;
    }

    // iterate through the whole string again and count ALL the characters
    // then subtract the number inside the strings from the total to get the number outside strings
    return StringUtil.countMatches(s, c) - count;
}
```

---

Instead you can just do something like this, which is much more efficient:

```
public static int countCharacterOutsideQuotes(CharSequence chars, char targetChar) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean isQuoted = false;
    // using `charAt` avoids doubling memory usage of copying all the chars into another array
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
        char c = chars.charAt(i);
        if (c == '"') {
            // found a quote, flip from not quoted to quoted or vice versa.
            isQuoted = !isQuoted;
        } else if (c == targetChar && !isQuoted) {
            // found the target character, if it's not inside quotes then count it
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

If you are reading the data from a file to start with then you might skip putting it in a string and instead just read it directly with a Reader, which will save memory and also eliminate the slowdown of having to wait for the file to be read before you can even start processing. By using a Reader, you can start processing immediately and you will hold only one character in memory at a time.

```
public static int countCharacterOutsideQuotes(Reader reader, char targetChar) throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(reader);
    int count = 0;
    boolean isQuoted = false;
    // using `charAt` avoids doubling memory usage of copying all the chars into another array
    for (int c = reader.read(); c != -1; c = reader.read()) {
        if (c == '"') {
            // found a quote, flip from not quoted to quoted or vice versa.
            isQuoted = !isQuoted;
        } else if (c == targetChar && !isQuoted) {
            // found the target character, if it's not inside quotes then count it
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new StringReader("your-test-string-goes-here"));) {
    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file.txt"));) {
        System.out.println(countCharacterOutsideQuotes(reader, '{'));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems obvious when you post this what I was doing inefficiently haha! I have had a rough week, this should have been such an easy thing for me.

I've changed up to use the method that you provided and it sped up the search by only 1 second. Unfortunately it is not a significant amount, but good nonetheless.

Comment: All fine, we all can have a brain farts and write silly code, I've done it plenty.. It helps to be very clear of your goal and to determine the general requirements and start with those; In this case the general requirement is that you have to iterate over the string to find and count the character. It is also important, when aiming for efficiency, to be aware of the methods that you call; In this case to know that `s.toCharArray()` is making a copy of your string and that `StringUtil.countMatches(s, c)` is iterating over `s` again.

Answer (score 0):

A loop might be more CPU efficient. But here, i would go for 2 stage regex:

```
String input="sdfg\"srfg{rmjy#\"rmyrmy{rymundh\"ecfvr{cerv#\"fes{dc\"cf2234TC@$#ct234\"etw243T@#$c\"nhg";


input=input.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"", ""); // becomes sdfgrmyrmy{rymundhfes{dcetw243T@#$c"nhg

input=input.replaceAll("[^{]", ""); //becomes {{

return input.length();//2
```

the second regex can use the actual character passed (if you limit it to { and } it should work.

```
input=input.replaceAll("[^"+c+"]", "");
```

and if we combine both regexes it becomes less readable but one line

```
input=input.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"|[^"+c+"]", "");
```

Comment: CPU efficiency is definitely the most important thing. I am parsing through a text files with 100 million + lines in it, and need to use this function on nearly every line. Currently the program only takes a couple seconds to do this, but is a noticeable drag for users. I was hoping maybe a regex solution would be quicker. the loop goes through in O(n) time, I am not sure the time complexity for regex though.

Comment: Btw, you have said the function looks for curly braces outside of quotes, but the code seems to look inside the quotes.

Comment: Inside the regex, the code still uses loops in one form or another without having the benefit of highly-optimized JITter code

Comment: It finds all braces, then subtracts the found within quotes. So effectively it does count those outside. In a backwards way though.... I guess that is what happens when it has been rewritten 100 times.

Comment: The method you proposed with regex, while cleaner looking, is 5.4 times slower than the loop method I initially used. So maybe it is as optimized as it can be, and we'll just have to deal with it.

Comment: That is to be expected, regex are used for ease, or when the performance is of a lesser concern.